# Explanation of what it means for $w(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ to satisfy equation 1

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Does satisfying equation 1 here mean that we sub $w(x)$ into equation 1? I do not understand the first statement and as a result the subsequent statements make no sense to me. If someone could provide a step by step substitution of what is happening , that would be really helpful. thanks so much!

equation 1 is : $y''+py'+qy=0$

[image]

Comment: Correct. You can say that $w$ satisfies (1) if you plug in $y=w(x)$ into that equation and you get a true statement for all values of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrei says, it just means letting $y = w$ in the equation. So you end up with

$$w'' + pw' + qw = 0\\
(u+iv)'' + p(u+iv)' + q(u + iv) = 0\\
u''+iv'' + pu' + ipv' + qu + iqv = 0\\
(u'' + pu' +qu) + i(v'' + pv' + qv) = 0$$
Because $u, v, p, q$ are all real, the left hand side is a complex number with real part $u'' + pu' +qu$ and imaginary part $v'' + pv' + qv$. A complex number is $0$ if and only if both its real and imaginary parts are $0$, so it must be that
$$u'' + pu' +qu = 0\\v'' + pv' + qv = 0$$